# How to draw tangential circles to the inside of a curve in Python using numpy and matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, geometry

I would like to plot circles which are tangents to the interior of a curve in Python as shown below:
[image]

I tried the following approach.
I created an inverted exponential curve to get the curve as shown below.

```
x = np.arange(0, 2, 0.1)
y = [1/np.exp(i) for i in x]
plt.plot(x, y, marker = "o")
```

[image]

To add a circle as tangent to the curve, I am adding a circle manually as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#Plot exponential curve
ax.plot(x, y)

#Add tangential circle manually
pi = np.pi
c1 = plt.Circle((x[1]+ np.sin(pi/4) * 0.1, y[1] + np.sin(pi/4) * 0.1),
                radius = 0.1, facecolor = "black", ec = "white")
ax.add_patch(c1)
```

[image]

Here my assumption is that the angle denoted by the shaded part in the figure below (between the normal radius and horizontal x-axis is 45 degrees).

[image]

However, I think this is an incorrect assumption and incorrect way to do it.
When I add more circles, they are not exactly tangential to the curve as shown below.

[image]

What would be the correct approach to draw the circles as tangents to the curve? Is it possible to do it in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using trigonometry (there is likely a way to simplify but I'm rusty+tired :p).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

X = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
Y = np.sin(X)

#Plot exponential curve
ax.plot(X, Y)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

#Add tangential circles
for i in np.arange(1,len(X),5):
    ax.plot(X[i], Y[i], marker='o', color='r')
    pi = np.pi
    radius = 0.3
    # slope of tangent
    dydx = np.gradient(Y)[i]/np.gradient(X)[i]
    # slope of perpendicular
    slope = 1/abs(dydx)
    # angle to horizontal
    angle = np.arctan(slope)
    c1 = plt.Circle((X[i] - np.sign(dydx)*np.cos(angle) * radius,
                     Y[i] + np.sin(angle) * radius),
                    radius = radius, facecolor = "black", ec = "white")
    ax.add_patch(c1)
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your function is `exp(-x)`

It's derivative is  `-exp(-x)`, so tangent vector at point `x, exp(-x)` is `(1, -exp(-x))` and normal vector is `(exp(-x), 1)` (note sign change).

Normalize it

```
n_len = np.hypot((y)[i], 1)
nx = y[i] / n_len
ny = 1 / n_len
```

center for radius `R` is

```
c1 = plt.Circle((x[i] + R * nx, y[i] + R * ny, ...
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be working fine after sixth element in x and y. But before that the circles are not tangential. Do you know why?

Comment: My mistake, should be 1 instead of x in vectors

Answer (score 1):

For the circle to be tangent, its center must be located along the normal to the curve (this is a straight-line with slope -δx/δy).

You did not specify how the radius varies, so there are two options:

- the radius is a function of x or y or s (curvilinear abscissa) that you supply; then place the center at the desired distance from the contact point, on the normal;
- the radius is such that it matches the local curvature; then what you want is the osculating circle; there is a formula to compute the radius of curvature.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle